# Order by number in Postgres JSONB column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonb

I have a `position` key defined in my JSONB column.

The values are treated as text, so the following query

```
MyModel.order("data ->> 'position' ASC").each {|x| puts x.position}
```

returns:

```
0
1
10
2
3
```

How can I treat `position` as integer and order my model based on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Purely a guess, but maybe:

```
MyModel.order("(data ->> 'position')::Integer ASC").each {|x| puts x.position}
```

Comment: Not bad for a guess :)